# Openlayers Graticule current interval

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

How can I get the current interval value of Graticule on zoom change?
There are Meridians and Parallels of the lines, from where I can calculate the value, but this is not the right approach.

Comment: Using the meridians is reliable https://codesandbox.io/s/graticule-forked-yh3063?file=/main.js  Otherwise you will need to replicate the calculated done in the source code https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/layer/Graticule.js#L1010-L1036

Comment: @Mike in first case meridians and parallels may not exist, if the map view is smaller than an interval, the second is too hard, better write own layer. Don't you know if I can use zoom integer value to index the Graticule interval?

Comment: Looking at the code `targetSize` option is the diagonal distance across a cell, which means the `intervals` will not relate to resolutions in a mercator projection as the parallels get proportionately further apart as the interval gets bigger.  But I have got the getInterval function based on the source working https://codesandbox.io/s/graticule-forked-yh3063?file=/main.js

Comment: I would better go with own layer, thank you @Mike